# How can I do if they dont give anymore their API?

Tags: api, tripadvisor, booking.com-api

Goodevening,
I have developed a website of villas, I need to sync each calendar of each villa to its relative Booking's calendar, Airbnb's calendar, Tripadvisor's calendar and Homeaway's calendar.

The problem is that actually, they dont give anymore APIs access, I don't know why and I don't know if one day we could request them again.
I have written to all four of these websites but no one interesting answer.

Do you know what's happening and how can I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: If they don't give access to their APIs, you can't fix it. As for what's happening, you'd have to ask them; StackOverflow users can't speak on behalf of off-site vendors or services.

Comment: I have asked to them but no one answered me about that

Comment: That doesn't change things here. No one here can answer this sort of question, because we are not them.